# How can terminated instances be removed from AWS SSM's inventory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-ssm

I'm trying to remove terminated managed nodes from SSM's inventory, but couldn't find any way to do so through either the CLI or through an SDK. Currently, when I run the command `aws ssm get-inventory` the resulting list contains a lot of entries of the following pattern:

```
{
    "Id": "i-0ffeeb0756265c10f",
    "Data": {
        "AWS:InstanceInformation": {
            "TypeName": "AWS:InstanceInformation",
            "SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "CaptureTime": "2022-09-09T05:11:53Z",
            "Content": [
                {
                    "InstanceId": "i-0ffeeb0756265c10f",
                    "InstanceStatus": "Terminated"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

These instances also do not show up in managed nodes in the AWS console. Is there a way to remove these terminated instances from the SSM inventory? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`aws ssm get-inventory` can use --filters.

> Key=string,Values=string,string,Type=string

For you:

> Key=InstanceStatus,Values=Terminated,Type=NotEqual

So something like this should work:

```
aws ssm get-inventory --filters Key=InstanceStatus,Values=Terminated,Type=NotEqual
```

This is just what I get from docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/get-inventory.html). I haven't tried it so may need some tweaking.